# A one-day loss statistics from Google

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics

My stats dropped 50 times
pls help me !
I did not see any problem with the site! 
Google also did not report any problems

url: **Food.Sooran.com**

200 was my previous online 
But now one people!

**The strange Tip!:**

Every few months, a high statistics comes a time for no reason!
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add the dates from where the drop starts. If you got those, check for Google Algoritm updates.

Comment: You seem to be operating a scraper site; I suspect you've been penalised.

Comment: This problem is so strange!
@Brendon did not get a penalty.

Comment: @Martijn 
But when I got my MVC architecture on this issue came into existence.

Comment: Which traffic source got hit the most? the second picture shows a huge spike in impressions during that time ... so I am guessing your organic traffic got hit the most, perhaps @Brendon could be right here?

Comment: @Prasad main source of my traffic is from google but after change cms(without change url and set 301) my Stats came down suddenly

Comment: @ErfanSafarpoor can you check for 404s in GWMT? Have they gone up?

Comment: @Prasad yes ,i had 10,000 404 error in google webmaster after change cms Architecture 
but after 6 mounth cleared from google (i used disallow in robots.txt for remove)

Comment: There lies your problem @ErfanSafarpoor ! You could have redirected the 404s to the proper pages using 301s. By using disallow, you are basically asking Google to stop crawling that section of your site, ergo to forget all the previously done good work by you (since now in the eyes of the search engine, all the good ranking urls are either missing - 404s, or not allowed to be indexed - disallowed).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16038/discussion-between-erfan-safarpoor-and-prasad).

Comment: @Prasad 
A very important question 
The next 404 pages erased and devalued 
I see very error in my Google webmaster. 
Do I need the error to MARK AS FIXED?
or no have reAction ?!

Comment: @Prasad pls answer last comment of me